# camus or gobblin which is preferable

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, camus, gobblin

Can you please help me in setting up camus or gobblin to store messages in HDFS from Kafka. A Working example could be great.

Gobblin is still in incubation phase and camus is phased out. So which one is preferable to use.

i downloaded gobblin and ran gobblin-standalone.sh start but i get the error

> Environment variable GOBBLIN_JOB_CONFIG_DIR not set! .

Comment: Asking for pre-written code on StackOverflow is not good practice. You would get more help if you wrote some code and asked a question if you ran into a problem you cannot fix yourself.

Comment: i downloaded gobblin and ran gobblin-standalone.sh start   but i get the error Environment variable GOBBLIN_JOB_CONFIG_DIR not set!
. Can you please help me from here.

Comment: Error message is self explanatory if you understand what an environmental variable is

Answer (score 2):

The Confluent Kafka Sink Connector for HDFS is the preferable one to use since it replaces Camus, supports the latest versions of Apache Kafka, is actively maintained, and is open source.

http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html